# Bilinear programming

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let us assume I have an optimization problem as follows:
[image]

The first feasible region is an ellipsoid, meaning that a and b belong to a known ellipsoid. The second feasible region is polyhedral (a set of linear equation). If I merge the two maximization, then the objective function will become bilinear.

How can I solve this problem at one shot?

I mean is there a way to convert this special bilinear problem to a (mixed-integer) convex problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can "merge" to a single maximization over all variables.

Then use Gurobi (which can solve bilinear problems such as this to global optimality, given enough time and memory) or a general global nonlinear optimization solver, such as BARON. No need to reinvent the wheel.

It's a very small problem, so I don't think it should be difficult for the solvers to handle. –

**Edit**: In response to the edited version of the question, which asks about converting the optimization problem to a mixed-integer convex optimization problem:
The answer is no, unless you perform binary expansions of two of the variables as an approximation to the original problem, and then use Big M to linearize the product terms. In my opinion that would be a terrible thing to do. Ut is much better to solve it as a bilinear problem with 4 variables - more accurate and likely faster.

Comment: Dear Mark, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to convex the whole problem, if merged? In fact, this is a part of a more complex optimization problem and I need it to be convex. Using Gurobi may not help.

Comment: It can't be convexified. You should start a new question, and put the optimization problem you really want to solve there.. The reason there are non-convex optimization solvers is because some problems are on-convex, and simplifying or altering then to be convex may result in a lousy problem and a lousy solution. You can concoct  your own alternating variables scheme or something and use a convex optimization solver to solve each subproblem, but  that is likely to be unreliable compared to using an off-the-shelf high quality non-convex solver; and at best give you a local optimum.

Comment: Thank you Mark. In  the case of the first level's feasible region  being a box set (1<a<4. for example), I knew already that we can find the optimal solution using the fact that it occurs at the extreme points or vertices (here 1 or 4). Thus, I thought there may be a way to apply to this special disjoint bilinear problem considering the convexity of the first land second levels' feasible space. By the way, I did not know that Gurobi solves bilinear problems to global optimality.

Comment: Global optimization solvers adaptively do whatever dividing up is needed. Your attempt to do your own is likely to be inferior, or possibly erroneous. Gurobi has had capability to globally optimize bilinear (non-convex quadratic in objective and/or constrains)  since Gurobi 9.0.0 in Nov 2019. Prior to that it only handled problems whose continuous relaxation is convex. Starting with Gurobi 11.0, just released, it now has capability for more general non-convex MINLP (i.e., not just bilinear).